# create middlware with input argument in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to create a misslware in nodejs for access Level , i create this middlware :

```
class AccessUser extends middlware {
  async AccessUser(access,req, res, next) {
    const getTokenFrom = (req) => {
      const authorization = req.headers["authorization"];
      if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer ")) {
        return authorization.substring(7);
      }
      return null;
    };
    const token = getTokenFrom(req);
    if (token) {
      jwt.verify(token, "shhhhh", (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return new ForbiddenResponse().Send(res);
        let permission = decoded.info.permission;
        let item = permission.find((x) => x.permissionId == access);
        if (!item) {
          return new ForbiddenResponse().Send(res);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

i add the argument name `access` to input of `AccessUser` in this middlware :

`async AccessUser(access,req, res, next)`

and i want to need compare the `access` with `x.permissionId` . but it show me this error :

> (node:2168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorization' of undefined

this error for this line :

`const authorization = req.headers["authorization"];`

and i use this middlware by this :

```
 router.post(
  "/Create",
  access.AccessUser("Role:Add")
);
```

**now whats the problem ? how can i use the middllware with input argument ?????**

Answer (score 0):

`AccessUser` is not a express middleware, the method signature has to be `(req,res,next)`.
You can get around this if you define `AccessUser` as a factory function (there's no need to define it async as you're not awaiting any async call):

```
class AccessUser  {
    accessUser(access) {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            const getTokenFrom = (req) => {
                const authorization = req.headers["authorization"];
                if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer ")) {
                    return authorization.substring(7);
                }
                return null;
            };
            const token = getTokenFrom(req);
            if (token) {
                jwt.verify(token, "shhhhh", (err, decoded) => {
                    if (err) return new ForbiddenResponse().Send(res);
                    let permission = decoded.info.permission;
                    let item = permission.find((x) => x.permissionId == access);
                    if (!item) {
                        return new ForbiddenResponse().Send(res);
                    } else {
                        next();
                    }
                });
            }// TODO: handle case if no token exists?
        }
    }
}
module.exports = AccessUser;
```

Then use it like this:

```
const AccessUserMiddleware = require('./path-to-access-middleware');
const AccessUser = new AccessUserMiddleware();
app.get('/', AccessUser.accessUser("Role:Add"));
```

Comment: it show this erro `uncaughtException: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: The function keyword was missing, can you try again?

Comment: i call in routing.js  `const { AccessUser } = require("./../../http/middllware/AccessUser");` and use that in route : `AccessUser("Role:Add"),` but it show me this error :` AccessUser is not a function``

Comment: Fixed the exports/imports. By the way - you should also handle the case when no token exists, see the TODO in my code